# iPhone Bookmark UIWebView - Displaying Page Title Instead of URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a fully operational web browser application that stores bookmarked pages.  When the bookmarks button is clicked, a listview of the stored websites is displayed.  Instead of showing the URL, I would like the listview to display the title of the page.  I am able to get the title of the page with the code below, but do not know how or where to implement it.

NSString *webSiteTitle = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];

I have included the .m and .h files for the two ViewControllers below.  Please show/tell me what to do.

Thank you!

**ExplorerViewController.h**

```
@interface ExplorerViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>{
    UITextField *urlField;
    UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton;
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
    UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton;
    UIBarButtonItem *bookMarksButton;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingActivity;
    UIWebView *webView;
    UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *urlField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *bookMarksButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingActivity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;

-(NSString*)repairURL:(NSString*)url;
-(IBAction)refreshWebView;
-(IBAction)goBack;
-(IBAction)goForward;
-(void)actualizeButtons;
-(IBAction)bookmarksButtonTapped;
-(IBAction)addBookmarkButtonTapped;

@end
```

**ExplorerViewController.m**

```
#import "ExplorerViewController.h"
#import "BookmarksViewController.h"

@implementation ExplorerViewController
@synthesize urlField;
@synthesize refreshButton;
@synthesize backButton;
@synthesize forwardButton;
@synthesize bookMarksButton;
@synthesize loadingActivity;
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize navigationBar;

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"Bookmarks"] mutableCopy];
        if (!bookmarks) {
            bookmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [bookmarks addObject:[[[[self webView]request] URL] absoluteString]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];
        [bookmarks release];
    }
}
```

**BookmarksViewController.h**

```
@class ExplorerViewController;
@interface BookmarksViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSMutableArray *bookmarks;
    ExplorerViewController *explorerView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bookmarks;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ExplorerViewController *explorerView;

-(IBAction)cancelButtonTapped;

@end
```

BookmarksViewController.m

```
#import "BookmarksViewController.h"
#import "ExplorerViewController.h"

@implementation BookmarksViewController
@synthesize bookmarks, explorerView;


-(IBAction)cancelButtonTapped {
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [bookmarks count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ExplorerViewController.m, replace :

```
[bookmarks addObject:[[[[self webView]request] URL] absoluteString]];
```

by :

```
[bookmarks addObject:[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]];
```

If you need to have also the URL, add an NSArray instead the NSString to store either the URL and the title.

Comment: Thank you!  I will need to store the URL and the Title, so that when the title is clicked the UIWebView goes to the URL.  I am very new to iPhone programming, is there any way you can show me how to do this in the code above?

Comment: So use instead :

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"kURL", [[[self.webView request] URL] absoluteString], @"kTitle", [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"], nil];

[bookmarks addObject:dictionary];

And in - tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: (in BookmarksViewController.m), replace :

cell.textLabel.text = [bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

by :

cell.textLabel.text = [[bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"kTitle"];

And implement tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: to do action when a cell is selected.